# How to filter tablix rows based on boolean report parameter in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

[image: NetWtGreaterThan0 is report parameter(boolean)]

[image: Net Wt. Difference is calculated column]

Here NetWtGreaterThan0 is a boolean report parameter. If value of NetWtGreaterThan0 is true than i want to show rows with Net Wt. Difference>0.000. Here Net Wt. Difference is calculated column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try.

In the Row Visibility, Show / Hide based on expression.

```
=IIF(Parameters!NetWtGreaterThan0.Value = False, False, IIF(Net Wt. Difference>0.000, False, True))
```